# Squid proxy MySQL authentication config

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm wondering to know how to configure squid server with MySQL authentication. I've found a config example following:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/local/squid/libexec/squid_db_auth --user dbusername --password dbuserpassword --plaintext --persist
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Web-Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 minute
auth_param basic casesensitive off
```

http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2010/08/configuring-squid-server-to.html

And tested on localhost. This worked well. But in my case, MySQL server is located on another server. So, I need to specify "Hostname" and "Port" of MySQL server.

Can you help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code make changes in `squid_db_auth` example below,

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=yourdbname;host=remotemysqlserverip";
```

Add the above line to your `squid_db_auth?. I have tested the same with SQUID 3.1.10.